# How to change different attributes of an object with only one function method in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have 3 textFields for name, age and gender in compose and use a uiState data class to hold the states of the inputs:

```
    data class UiState( 
         val nameInput: String = "", 
         val ageInput: String = "", 
         val genderInput: String = "", 
     )
```

To update the states I use the following functions for the onValueChanged function (one function for each attribute: name, age and gender) of the textfields:

```
fun updateNameInput(input: String) { 
         _uiState.update { it.copy(nameInput = input) } 
     } 
  
     fun updateAgeInput(input: String) { 
         _uiState.update { it.copy(ageInput = input) } 
     } 
  
     fun updateGenderInput(input: String) { 
         _uiState.update { it.copy(genderInput = input) } 
     }
```

Now my question is, how can I boil those 3 functions into one and pass in the argument (eighter nameInput, ageInput or genderInput) in the function definition and update only that argument.

I want to be able to use only one function to be used to update eighter of those 3 textfields.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: Hi, my use case is, I have 3 OutlinedTextFields which hold their state by a uiState variable. And to update the state I would like to use only one function method for all 3 different TextFields without the need to habe a function for every single TextField.

Answer (score 1):

To put it in one function, I suppose you could make the function parameters optional and create new copies for the ones that are non-null. Then you can make null default arguments to allow them to be optional.

```
 fun updateNonNullInput(name: String? = null, age: String? = null, gender: String? = null) { 
     _uiState.update {
         var value = it
         if (name != null) value = value.copy(nameInput = name)
         if (age != null) value = value.copy(ageInput = age)
         if (gender != null) value = value.copy(genderInput = gender)
         value
     }
 }
```

Comment: This is not working unfortunately.